# creating array of struct c

Tags: c, file-io, struct

So I'm using struct to create an address that looks like this:

```
typedef struct Address{
    char street[100];
    char city[100];
    char state[3];
    int zip;
}address;
```

I have a txt file that looks like this:

```
123 Anywhere
Spokane
WA
99223
500 Sprague Ave
Spokane
WA
99201
319F CEB
Cheney
WA
99004
```

When I read in the file I get a huge problem. It will read in a couple of lines correctly but most everything else is wrong. Any numbers are completely wrong.

```
int fillArray(address *array, FILE * fin){
int i=0, total=0;
do{
    fgets(array[i].street, 100, fin);
    fgets(array[i].city, 100, fin);
    fgets(array[i].state, 3, fin);      
    fgets(array[i].street, 100, fin);
    fscanf(fin, "%d", &array[i].zip);
    total++;
    i++;
}while(!feof(fin));

return total;
}
```

Obviously I'm doing something wrong but I'm not sure what I'm doing wrong. I thought that if I use fgets, it will get the line and then store it into the area that I needed it to. I had used fscanf for everything before hand and I didn't get anywhere either. It would just get the 123 and then Anywhere into the next places since it goes until the first whitespace it sees. Is there a way to use fscanf to get the entire line, or isn't that what fgets does? Is there a simpler way of doing this? Yes I know that I shouldn't use while(!feof(fin)), but our teacher is teaching that right now and that is what I'm going to be using for the time being. Thank you in advance. I have been searching around online and can't seem to get where I need to go.

Comment: What do you mean by "It will read in a couple of lines correctly but most everything else is wrong."? Can you be more specific?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The code is reading `street` twice.  Perhaps try deleting that second one.

Unrelated tip:  Instead of hard coding the length such as 100, use the `sizeof` operator.  For example,

```
fgets(array[i].street, sizeof(array[i].street), fin);
```

Comment: hahaha, I didn't even see that. Fixed a lot of the issues. Now when I print, the first address is fine but then everything else is messed up.

Comment: Is the array of structures initialized (either on the stack or with malloc)?

Comment: what would cause a negative number to appear in a string? `Sp --1216999988okane` is what is appearing when I print

Comment: Also - I think you should add a \n to the end of the fscanf string for the zip to consume the line feed.

Comment: our teacher set `struct Address array[10]` in the main file. I'm not sure that I can modify that though

Comment: that worked thanks! I was trying to figure out how to get the \n but couldn't remember